# Bootstrap modal on hidden does not trigger

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Like the title says i have problem to getting the modal.on('hidden') event to run. I can open the modal without any problems. The code im using for it looks something like this:

```
var info = $('<img src="img/icons/info.png">');
info.attr('data-toggle','modal');
info.attr('data-target','#infoPopup');
```

The modal itself looks like this:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="infoPopup" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 id="popupHeader" class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="popupBody" class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It Opens perfectly fine but it seems like the hidden event is not triggert when I'm closing it by clicking beside the modal the close button or the X on the top right.

```
$('.modal.in').on('hidden',function(){
            console.log('test');
        });
```

The selected modal is the correct one when i'm trying to access it on the console with `$('.modal.in')`. So i'm not trying to get a callback on the wrong modal. I also tried it with `$('.modal.in').on('hidden.bs.modal',func...)`. But i got the same result.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using .modal.in use the id of the modal that you want to fire the event with.  If you want to use it for all modals just use .modal and not .modal.in and you will use on hidden.bs.modal

here is a fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/oqzfu7bg/)

```
$('#infoPopup').on('hidden.bs.modal',function(){
  alert("Modal Closed");
});
```

Comment: OH LORD PLS THROW BRAIN FROM HEAVEN. I just had the wrong  script loading order your way works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

for bootstrap 3 you need to use `hidden.bs.modal`

```
$('.modal.in').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    // do something…
})
```

if your modal is not in DOM on load this should rather work

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal','.modal.in', function () {
    // do something…
})
```